# Sextorsion then Trojan

Tags: malware, email, trojan, blackmail

I received an email containing blackmail about videos that the hacker said he recorded. He said that he recorded the user of the laptop masturbating and he is asking for money to delete them otherwise he'll send it to the user's family.

First I thought that it was fake because this is how it looks like, but to be sure I scanned my laptop with avast and at the end, I found that there was a malware called: Cryptominer -L [Trj]

Should I be scared? Or are the two problems related? What can the Trojan do and what should I do please?

Mail :

> Good morning! Your system has been hacked with a Trojan horse virus.
> It entered your device through adult portals that you visit.
>
> Some spicy videos contain malicious code that activates right after
> activation. All data has already been copied to my servers.
>
> I have full control over your device with which you access the
> Internet. I can see your screen, use your microphone and the camera
> without you ever noticing.
>
> I have already made a screen recording. A video was edited with a
> pornographic film that you were watching at the time and with your
> masturbation.
>
> Your face is perfectly visible and I don't think this kind of content
> will have a positive impact on your reputation.
>
> I have full access to your social media contacts and profiles. I can
> send this video from your messaging or E-mail.
>
> If you don't want this to happen, just take a simple step.
>
> Simply transfer 1100 USD (US dollars) to Bitcoin wallet:
> bc1qcnhtdk9tajwxup5vzkh9f08g2r0vuskfpdrwrl (in bitcoin equivalent at
> the exchange rate for the moment of the transfer)
>
> You can find detailed instructions in Google. After payment I will
> remove the video and virus from your device and no one will bother you
> anymore. If I don't receive payment within the expected time, all of
> your data and videos will be publicly available.
>
> I give you 2 working days.
>
> I receive a notification right after you read this letter. The timer
> starts immediately. Any complaints, including against the police,
> would be unnecessary. My wallet and email cannot be tracked. If I find
> out that you shared this post with someone else, the video will be
> released to the public immediately.
>
> I will destroy your reputation forever and all of your data will
> become open for everyone.
>
> Everyone will know your passion for porn sites and more. Changing
> passwords won't help, as all the data is already on my servers.
>
> Remember that reputation is very important and be careful!

Comment: Hard to tell for sure but I think these are unrelated things. Note that the mail you cite only makes  broad claims and does not provide any kind of verifiable prove for these claims - very likely because these are just lies to scare you.

Comment: This email is well-known. It just gets copy/pasted everywhere.

Comment: If this was real, they would definitely have given you some sample of the content they have. In any case, don't pay. You have zero guarantee they will not bother you again (in fact, it probably increases the chances of them bothering you again, because they know you will pay.)